# Freshly installed MySQL server 5.7.12 fails to start on FreeBSD 10.3

Tags: mysql, freebsd

```
root@w:/var/db # pkg install mysql57-server mysql57-client
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The following 6 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

New packages to be INSTALLED:
        mysql57-server: 5.7.12
        mysql57-client: 5.7.12
        liblz4: 131
        libevent2: 2.0.22_1
        perl5: 5.20.3_12
        libedit: 3.1.20150325_2

The process will require 293 MiB more space.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[1/6] Installing liblz4-131...
[1/6] Extracting liblz4-131: 100%
[2/6] Installing libevent2-2.0.22_1...
[2/6] Extracting libevent2-2.0.22_1: 100%
[3/6] Installing perl5-5.20.3_12...
[3/6] Extracting perl5-5.20.3_12: 100%
[4/6] Installing libedit-3.1.20150325_2...
[4/6] Extracting libedit-3.1.20150325_2: 100%
[5/6] Installing mysql57-client-5.7.12...
[5/6] Extracting mysql57-client-5.7.12: 100%
[6/6] Installing mysql57-server-5.7.12...
===> Creating users and/or groups.
Using existing group 'mysql'.
Using existing user 'mysql'.
[6/6] Extracting mysql57-server-5.7.12: 100%
Message from perl5-5.20.3_12:
The /usr/bin/perl symlink has been removed starting with Perl 5.20.
For shebangs, you should either use:

#!/usr/local/bin/perl

or

#!/usr/bin/env perl

The first one will only work if you have a /usr/local/bin/perl,
the second will work as long as perl is in PATH.
Message from mysql57-client-5.7.12:
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

This is the mysql CLIENT without the server.
for complete server and client, please install databases/mysql57-server

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
Message from mysql57-server-5.7.12:
*****************************************************************************

Remember to run mysql_upgrade the first time you start the MySQL server
after an upgrade from an earlier version.

Initial password for first time use of MySQL is saved in $HOME/.mysql_secret
ie. when you want to use "mysql -u root -p" first you should see password
in /root/.mysql_secret

*****************************************************************************

*****************************************************************************

Please keep in mind that the default location for my.cnf will be changed
from "/var/db/mysql/my.cnf" to "/usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf" in the near
future.  If you do not want to move your my.cnf to the new location then
you must set "mysql_optfile" in /etc/rc.conf to "/var/db/mysql/my.cnf".

*****************************************************************************
root@w:/var/db # service mysql-server start
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server: WARNING: failed precmd routine for mysql
```

Freshly created `/var/db/mysql` is empty.  No detailed log gets generated.

When I run

```
root@w:/usr/home# /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe
2016-05-16T03:54:08.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/db/mysql/w.err'.
2016-05-16T03:54:08.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
2016-05-16T03:54:30.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/w.pid ended
```

`/var/db/mysql` gets populated with error log containing:

```
root@w:/usr/home# cat /var/db/mysql/w.err
2016-05-16T03:54:08.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
2016-05-16T03:54:08.544447Z 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 28782 (request: 32929)
2016-05-16T03:54:08.546962Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 14310 (requested 16384)
2016-05-16T03:54:08.877416Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2016-05-16T03:54:08.877476Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2016-05-16T03:54:08.879883Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.12-log) starting as process 5817 ...
2016-05-16T03:54:09.009616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-05-16T03:54:09.009717Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-05-16T03:54:09.009740Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-05-16T03:54:09.009760Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-05-16T03:54:09.010701Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-05-16T03:54:09.011155Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-05-16T03:54:09.099785Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-05-16T03:54:09.137209Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-05-16T03:54:09.155602Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2016-05-16T03:54:09.155939Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/var/db/mysql/ibdata1' size to 128 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-05-16T03:54:09.157965Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Progress in MB:
 100
2016-05-16T03:54:11.334877Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/var/db/mysql/ibdata1' size is now 128 MB.
2016-05-16T03:54:11.336349Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file /var/db/mysql/ib_logfile101 size to 256 MB
2016-05-16T03:54:11.337459Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Progress in MB:
 100 200
2016-05-16T03:54:18.938775Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file /var/db/mysql/ib_logfile1 size to 256 MB
2016-05-16T03:54:18.940833Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Progress in MB:
 100 200
2016-05-16T03:54:23.966828Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file /var/db/mysql/ib_logfile101 to /var/db/mysql/ib_logfile0
2016-05-16T03:54:23.967235Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-05-16T03:54:23.967333Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2016-05-16T03:54:23.967563Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/var/db/mysql/ibtmp1' size to 128 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-05-16T03:54:23.967885Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Progress in MB:
 100
2016-05-16T03:54:26.098879Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/var/db/mysql/ibtmp1' size is now 128 MB.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.099216Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2016-05-16T03:54:26.431555Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2016-05-16T03:54:26.448924Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.448975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.456331Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.498113Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2016-05-16T03:54:26.498261Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.500368Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.500416Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.502198Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: sys_virtual table created
2016-05-16T03:54:26.502471Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-05-16T03:54:26.556412Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.12 started; log sequence number 0
2016-05-16T03:54:26.557067Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 17410ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2016-05-16T03:54:26.573311Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-05-16T03:54:26.590491Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
mysqld: Error on delete of './auto.cnf' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2016-05-16T03:54:26.654121Z 0 [Warning] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.

2016-05-16T03:54:26.654286Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator variables, current_pid: 5817, server_start_time: 1463370848, bytes_sent: 0,
2016-05-16T03:54:26.657718Z 0 [Note] Generated uuid: 'e252a097-1b19-11e6-97db-06754000002e', server_start_time: 1637339940989262617, bytes_sent: 35009826816
2016-05-16T03:54:26.657779Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: e252a097-1b19-11e6-97db-06754000002e.
2016-05-16T03:54:26.663993Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-05-16T03:54:27.860239Z 0 [Note] Auto generated SSL certificates are placed in data directory.
2016-05-16T03:54:27.869223Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2016-05-16T03:54:28.691388Z 0 [Note] Auto generated RSA key files are placed in data directory.
2016-05-16T03:54:28.693717Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2016-05-16T03:54:28.693842Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2016-05-16T03:54:28.695028Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2016-05-16T03:54:28.702943Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-05-16T03:54:28.704660Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-05-16T03:54:28.705527Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-05-16T03:54:28.706304Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708768Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708810Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708832Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708850Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708866Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708882Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708898Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708913Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708928Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708943Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708959Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708975Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.708990Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709005Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709020Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709035Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709050Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709066Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709081Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709096Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709111Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709126Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709141Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709156Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709171Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709187Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709215Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709238Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709255Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709271Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709299Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709316Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709331Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709346Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.709362Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-05-16T03:54:28.710173Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-05-16T03:54:28.710419Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-05-16T03:54:28.817932Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/db/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-05-16T03:54:28.818265Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 160516  5:54:28
2016-05-16T03:54:30.077783Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1209970
2016-05-16T03:54:30.078115Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2016-05-16T03:54:30.078143Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.078170Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.086964Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.087053Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.087084Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.087110Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.087127Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.087338Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-05-16T03:54:30.094312Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2016-05-16T03:54:30.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/w.pid ended
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes I did.  I also removed more packages and re-installed them and now I have another problem.   See updated question above.

Comment: What do the mysql-server logs say ?

Comment: nothing gets generated.  `/var/db/mysql` is empty

Comment: @krl Start the server from command line typing: mysqld (or mysqld_safe) in a SSH shell and post the output.

Comment: @bleemboy ok, that got me somewhere, now I have an error log file.  see updated question.

Comment: Not sure why this was at -2, I just ran into this. If it's not a bug, it's completely different from how previous versions behaved without any warning as to what should be expected... In fact, it does say one thing that it does (`/root/.mysql_secret`), however it doesn't actually do that step lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log shows you didn't create yet a MySQL root user:

```
2016-05-16T03:54:28.704660Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-05-16T03:54:28.705527Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Not all installation scripts create them automatically.

To create a root user, run `mysqld --initialize --user=mysql [with random root password]`.

Comment: Actually it must be `mysqld --initialize --user=mysql`.  Please update.  Without `--user=mysql` it gets messed up again.

Comment: Initializing the Data Directory Manually Using mysqld: ```On Unix and Unix-like systems, it is important to make sure that the database directories and files are owned by the mysql login account so that the server has read and write access to them when you run it later. To ensure this if you run mysqld as root, include the --user option``` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remove existing database folder:

```
rm -rf /var/db/mysql
```

Then, open **/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server** script for editing.

Find **mysql_create_auth_tables()** function.
In this function, replace the following line:

```
eval $mysql_install_db $mysql_install_db_args >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

with:

```
eval $procname --initialize --basedir=/usr/local --datadir=${mysql_dbdir} --user=${mysql_user} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Start MySQL Server:

```
service mysql-server start
```

Here's one way to set MySQL root password:

```
mysql -uroot
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New_ROOT_Password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'New_ROOT_Password';
exit
```

In case of any issues, comment the *>/dev/null 2>/dev/null* part.
Without this log redirection, **mysqld** will spit out messages of deprecated options such as *mysql_install_db* and you will be able to debug further.